# Magento Front End 404 Error

Tags: mysql, magento, content-management-system

I am a newbie to magento, I have installed and put a few products, but then later I was getting Error:404 page not found in the front end. Backend is all OK, I am able to access everything but all of a sudden I don't know how this happened. I tried all the solutions like Flush Cache, replacing .htaccess, is_active field in database etc but all proved futile. Then lately I have put in system->Configuration->Web Base_url as http://sportiva.no/index.php/ (Previously it was http://sportiva.no/) and all is completely changed all the styles went away and I am not able to save anything. Please help, I am ready to give backend credentails.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Go to System > Configuration > Web > Default Pages and check "CMS Home Page" field value. If it is "404 Not Found", then change it to any of the CMS page available on the drop-down and save the configuration.

Comment: I have done it but still the same. Can you please do it for me?

Comment: are you looking at it now?

Comment: Hi Mahmood. I am looking into it. I found that you have not set theme for your frontend. What is your theme name.

Comment: ma_sportshop is the theme

Comment: In database go to core_config_data and check the url.

Comment: Go to System > Configuration > Design > Themes and set Templates,Skin and Layout fields values.

Comment: Hey vinoth, I managed to fixed the issue by giving a rewrite rule in .htaccess. Thanks for your help buddy.

Comment: What changes you made can you please revert back?

Answer (score 0):

Refere to this link by Alan Storm,

http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/6462298634/404-debugging

excerpt from it,

Put this code in function `_validateControllerClassName`

```
<?php
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php

    /**
     * Generating and validating class file name,
     * class and if evrything ok do include if needed and return of class name
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function _validateControllerClassName($realModule, $controller)
    {
        $controllerFileName = $this->getControllerFileName($realModule, $controller);        
        if (!$this->validateControllerFileName($controllerFileName)) {
            var_dump($controllerFileName);
            return false;
        }

        $controllerClassName = $this->getControllerClassName($realModule, $controller);
        if (!$controllerClassName) {
            var_dump($controllerClassName);
            return false;
        }

        // include controller file if needed
        if (!$this->_includeControllerClass($controllerFileName, $controllerClassName)) {
            var_dump($controllerFileName . '----' . $controllerClassName);
            return false;
        }

        return $controllerClassName;
    }
```

Comment: Tried putting this function but still the same

Comment: This function is here just to help you to investigate where the problem is. It will resolve anything...